# Is designing a small GA airplane with a wing loading of 20-25 lbs/sq ft a bad idea, or is that wing loading too high?

Tags: aerodynamics

Is designing a small GA plane like the following a bad idea?

This question is not the same asking if a an airplane with a traditional design is safer with a lower wing loading.

This question specifically asks if there are any reasons not to design a small slow landing plane such as a non-USA ultralight with a specific wing loading of 20-25 sq ft, and gives specific design suggestions to counter against popular reasons why an airplane shouldn't be designed at that wing loading.

Is designing a small GA plane like the following a bad idea?

Similar to the Cri Cri but with a wing loading of 20-25lbs/sq ft, slotted flaps, similar 17% airfoil to a Zenith 701, for low a weight spar, wing twist and vg's for better stall resistance,  twin engine, MTOW of 600 lbs, so wing area of 30 sq ft, 15 ft span, 2 ft chord, and a stall speed of 30-45mph (assuming all the math works out)?

This reduces the argument that high wing loading planes must land at a high speed and use low profile wings, which are easier to stall.

It seems many small airplanes are designed in the 10-14lbs/sq ft range, except for the BD5 at 17 lbs/sq ft (popular longer wings), and Rutan's Catbird at 45lbs/sq ft.

Wouldn't smaller wings, smaller spar, lower weight, less drag and less horsepower requirements be advantageous?

Approximate wing loading of various aircraft:

Cessna 172 - 14lbs/sq ft

CriCri - 11

Zenith 601 - 10

BD5 - 17

Rutan Catbird - 45lbs/sq ft

Comment: Where did you get the catbird figure? That doesn't seem right

Comment: I'm finding the Cirrus SR20 has a wing loading of 22.2 and the SR22 23.5, so it doesn't seem too out of line.

Comment: @ Fred Larson: Thanks for getting back to me. This is great news! Definitely going to design my plane in the 20-25lbs/sq ft range. Don't know why the moderators decided this wasn't important and decided to close this post -bad for aviation - good for me! If more designers designed planes in this range, aviation would look much different with longer distance flights, lighter planes and more places to land! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Racing airplanes do that and live with high landing speeds.  25 psf is about the wing loading of a [Beech Baron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_Baron).  The Baron stalls in the landing configuration, gear and ***flaps*** down, at 84 mph/73kt.

This mean you fly approaches at 110 mph ***with flaps***.  Not too many GA pilots are safe with an airplane that hot without a lot of extra training and lord help you if you have to put the thing in a field that fast (a single I mean, the Baron being a twin and the expectation of off field landings being low).

You can make the flaps fancier, and maybe get that down under 100 mph, and then add wing slats and maybe get it down to 90, but you just added a lot of weight and cost.  Not worth it for a few knots at the top.